# closing process.stdout after using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

Assume using `subprocess.Popen()` method to run a basic Shell command - `'ls -l'` which gives a list of files in the CWD. Your code will go something like this.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p=Popen(['ls','-l'],stdout=PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
p.stdout.close()
```

Instead of multiple lines, you decide to put it in a single line and end up with

```
print Popen(['ls','-l'],stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I don't see where the `p.stdout.close()` fits here. Is there any way I could close the stdout of this subprocess? I am using `Python 2.6`. I know about `check_output()` in Python 2.7 but I have to stick to 2.6. Is there any potential security or performance issue that I might end up with if I keep opening the output PIPE streams and not closing them?

Comment: Not sure about security implications, but you could write yourself a context manager to not have to call close by yourself all the time. In there you can even have conditional code paths depending on your version of Python.

Comment: It's a situation where I cannot go for context managers. I need to call a certain process repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably you can use a with statment for auto close and write the code using oneliner. But before that some ground work can be done. Check out the below code**.

```
from subprocess import Popen

class MyPopen(Popen):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.stdout:
            self.stdout.close()
        if self.stderr:
            self.stderr.close()
        if self.stdin:
            self.stdin.close()
        # Wait for the process to terminate, to avoid zombies.
        self.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyPopen(['ls','-l'],stdout=PIPE) as p:
        print(p.communicate()[0])
```

Comment: If `Popen` is a context manager already, you probably should call the parent methods of `__enter__` and `__exit__` as well (or not, depending on implementation).

Comment: This is working fine. I found out that check output here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output from python 2.7+ does what I really intended to. It returns the output which can be captured in variables.